# MySql get total count of an ID

Tags: mysql, count, subquery

Sorry for not so clear title.

I have table with columns,

```
ID, p1_ID, p2_ID, winner
```

where I want to find the percentage of winning using a single query.

I can get a total win count of users via the folowing query, I also tried to get the total counts, but its returning null,

```
SELECT count(winner) as ranking, winner, @togal_games 
FROM `gscore`, (select count(*) from `gscore` where p1_ID= winner or p2_ID = winner) as togal_games
group by winner
order by ranking desc
```

Results:

```
5   234234  NULL
3   453453  NULL
1   345344  NULL
```

Can some one identify how to solve or where to look to improve my sql queries like this one ?

**Edit: Added Sample Data**

```
ID  P1_ID   P2_ID   WINNER
1   234234  345344  234234
2   234234  345344  345344
3   234234  453453  234234
4   123123  234234  234234
5   234234  123123  234234
6   453453  345344  453453
7   345344  234234  234234
8   234234  453453  453453
9   453453  234234  453453
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some sample data set together with your expected resultset

Comment: It's not clear to me what "total games" you're attempting to count. The total number of games the winner played, or the total he player against that component or the number of total games played overall or...?

Comment: total games that the winner has played ever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your sample dataset you can do so

```
select pid ,count(id) total_played,
sum(pid= WINNER) `wins`,
(sum(pid= WINNER) / count(id)) * 100  percent
from (
select `ID`, `P1_ID` pID, `WINNER` from t
  union all
select `ID`, `P2_ID` pID, `WINNER` from t
) tt
group by pID
order by total_played DESC
```

### [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4b52/21)

You can use `union all` in order to have all players in one column just as i did in above then you can group your query by players so `count(id)` will give you the count of played matches for each player,I have calculated the win matches by `sum(pid= WINNER)` in mysql if you use any expression in sum function this will result as boolean so we got count of matches win by each user by comparing player id with the winner column,and the last part i have calculated the percetage